# How do I propagate error for a Poisson-binomial distribution (sum of probability estimates with standard deviations)

Tags: error-propagation, poisson-binomial-distribution

My question is about quantifying the uncertainty associated with a sum of several probabilities, in a case where the probabilities are unequal and are themselves estimates with associated uncertainty (standard deviations).

Let's consider a situation where we're interested in frogs, and in estimating how many species are likely to occur in the pond at the local park. Based on the characteristics of the pond, there are four species that might be there with occurrence probabilities of 0.35, 0.50, 0.72, and 0.98. We also have standard deviations for these occurrence probabilities (0.08,0.12,0.07,0.02). We want the expected number of frog species E(F), where F is the number of frog species.

Given these conditions, it seems that the number of frog species would be described by a Poisson binomial distribution so, where pf is a vector representing the occurrence probabilities of each of the frog species,

E(F) = sum(pf) 
     = 0.35 + 0.50 + 0.72 + 0.98

where pf is a vector and it would seem that the variance should be:

Var(F)= sum((1-pf)*pf) 
       = (1-0.35)*0.35 +(1-0.50)*0.50 +(1-0.72)*0.72 +(1-0.98)*0.98

However, this variance is only correct if pf are fixed known quantities but in this case, each occurrence probability is uncertain. So how can that uncertainty best be captured in the calculation of a variance (or confidence interval, or prediction interval)?

Answer (score 0):

If the frog occurrences are independent, you can indeed sum the variances to obtain the variance of the sum. However, I do not understand why you need this distributional assumption, use the standard deviations on the occurrence probabilities you have to calculate this variance:

$$Var(F) = 0.08^2 + 0.12^2 + 0.07^2 + 0.02^2 $$

This assumes that you have real standard deviations, and not standard errors of the occurrence probability *estimates*.

But I should stress again that this only holds when occurrences are independent, which feels unlikely to me in this case. If the covariances are non-zero your mean calculation is still correct, but the variance is off. For instance, if frogs tend to occur together (positive covariances), then the variance is expected to be larger than the formula I gave, but still easy to calculate knowing that $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2Cov(X,Y)$.

Comment: In this case we're willing to assume that the probabilities are independent, but the standard deviations are for the estimates (they are derived from cross-validation).

Comment: Sorry to bump a very old thread, but could you add more information about how to deal with this problem when indeed we don't have access to real standard deviations, but only estimated from observations?